# Create BigQuery job using access token

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I have a google `access_token` I want to use to authenticate when creating a BigQuery query job. Using the service account json works fine.

I have this:

```
client = new BigQuery({
    token: accessToken,
    projectId: 'my-project'
});

return await client.createQueryJob(sql);
```

It's still using the service account credentials. All other things I run using the token works fine.

Below is the example of running the REST API without the Google client APIs.

```
const resp = await fetch(     
    'https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/my-project/jobs',
    {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            configuration: {
                query: {
                    query: sql,
                    useLegacySql: false
                }
            }
        })
    }
);
const j = await resp.json();
```

How do I get the client API to use the token?

Comment: Does this help? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization

Comment: @GrahamPolley Thanks, but not really. I can use the rest APIs directly but I want to use the client libraries instead.

Comment: try this: `const options = {
    token: 'accessToken',
    projectId: 'my-project',
  };

  const bigquery = new BigQuery(options);
..`

https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/92119e3b23874263d9529283194a149b358b7c9f/src/bigquery.ts#L184

Comment: @GrahamPolley That's exactly like my example...

Comment: Yup, you're right. JS isn't my strong point. But, the docs/API does clearly say you can use an access token. Odd. Sorry man, I'm stumped.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are you validating that it's still using the service credentials?

Comment: It shows in the BigQuery logs. Also, we use the DataStudio explore function to review the result after running the query and the user needs access to the temp tables as they can only be viewed by the user creating them. The latter can be fixed by creating "real" tables that both the user and the service account has access to but that would prevent us from setting the quotas on anything other than the service account.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm trying to do the same thing but hitting the same wall. Thanks!

Comment: @jperry1147I did not. I ended up writing a wrapper around the api. It's what the client library is anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

As per this [link](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/BigQuery.html), you need to use the following code to specify explicit credentials when initialising the BigQuery client:

`const bigquery = new BigQuery({
  projectId: 'your-project-id',
  keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'
});`

That is to say, the only way to use explicit credentials is done with the json keyfile associated to the service account.

I hope that helps

Comment: No, you can run as another user using the `access_token`. If I use the REST API it works as expected but I want to use the recommended way and use the client API.

Comment: The OP asked about using an access token. This is using a service account.

Comment: @Asken Is that documented for the client library? If so, where?

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/92119e3b23874263d9529283194a149b358b7c9f/src/bigquery.ts#L184

Comment: In this case I would advice that you open a ticket with GCP.

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since you asked but since this took me a while to figure out, in case anyone else gets stuck this is what worked for me in the end (using a refresh token rather than access token):

```
const bigquery = new BigQuery({
    projectId: 'gcp-project-id',
    clientOptions: {
        refreshToken: 'askldjfaklsjdf',
    },
});
```